# Altair selection_single returning a vector: how to handle this in transform_filter?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a question about an interactive heatmap + linked scatterplot. You can play with it [here](http://leonardocerliani.droppages.com/heatplot.html).

The heatmap shows an `N x N` matrix, while the scatterplot shows a selection of values in an `N x N x M` matrix.

When you click the `[i,j]` cell in the heatmap, the scatteplot shows all the `[i,j,:]` values in the 3D matrix (the values are also coded by group, but this is not relevant for the issue I would like to ask about).

To implement this, I used `alt.selection_single`, but as far as I am aware, the examples in the Altair documentation deal with cases where this returns a scalar. In my case, the selection actually returns the vector `[i,j]` of the cell location in the heatmap.

I was not sure how to implement this, so I gave it a try... You can see the code below, and I would like to ask if you find it correct. Specifically, the lines with `selector` and with `transform_filter`. In the latter I also commented a line with the kind of logic that I hope the `selector` is implementing.

P.S.: Altair is amazing! :O)

```
selector = alt.selection_single(empty = 'all', fields=['rows','cols'])
base = alt.Chart(df).add_selection(selector)

figsize = 600

heatmap = (
    base
    .mark_rect()
    .encode(
      x='rows:N',
      y='cols:N',
      color='tval:Q',
      tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('rows:N', title='ROI 1'),
        alt.Tooltip('cols:N', title='ROI 2'),
        alt.Tooltip('tval:Q', title='T value')
      ]
    )
    .properties(width = figsize, height = figsize)
)



scatterplot = (
    base
    .mark_circle(size=60)
    .encode(
        x = 'group:N',
        y = 'count:Q',
        tooltip = ['subj'],
        color = 'group:N'
    )
    .transform_filter(
        # (datum.rows=='leonardo') & (datum.cols=='caterina')
        selector
    )
    .properties(width = figsize/2, height = figsize)
)


heatmap | scatterplot
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... the code seems to be working as intended?

Comment: hi @jakevdp. It looks to me like it's working as intended, but I generated the data for the scatterplot randomly, so I cannot look directly into whether the selection is correct. Specifically, is it correct to assume that the selector returns an array of two elements which in this case correspond to the index of the ith row and the jth column? Do I maybe need to use two selectors, one for row and the other for column? If so, can I combine it into the same transform filter? Thanks Jake!

Comment: The selector does not return an array (it doesn't really return anything), but the selection will include all data where the value specified fields match those of the selected item or items.

Comment: thanks @jakevdp, then it's correct :O) Thank you so much for Altair!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `encodings` or `fields` within an altair selection, it specifies which data properties the selection *projects* over. Since your selection projects over the fields `"rows"` and `"cols"`, what this means is that any data element that has the same value of `"rows"` **and** `"cols"` as the selected element will be included in the selection.

When you filter over this selection, the filter operation keeps all data entries with matching `"rows"` and `"cols"` values.